# SharePoint 2010 Mobile Connectors

Tags: development, web-services, mobile

We were looking to create SharePoint connectors for mobile.........which will provide some of the SharePoint features on mobile like

Content management, Document Management, Re-branding etc....or any other SharePoint feature

Can anybody suggest how to move forward?????

Or what are the SharePoint  features which are feasible to be used in mobile view.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The posts below may be helpful in understanding the mobile capabilities of SharePoint 2010 and more (e.g., Office 2010 & development) -

- [Mobility in Office 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2009/11/20/mobility-in-office-2010.aspx)
- [Configure SharePoint Server 2010 for Mobile Device Access](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2010/03/09/configure-sharepoint-server-2010-for-mobile-device-access.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2010 Mobile Web Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointandwindowsphone7trainingcourse_mobilewebdevelopmentunit_unit.aspx)